# Is an ES module which exports an object instance considered "service locator" pattern

Tags: javascript, theory

Imagine I have three files:

```
// thing.js
class Thing {}

var instance = new Thing()

export default instance
```

and two clients

```
// a.js
import thing from './thing'
```

and

```
// b.js
import thing from './thing'
```

Javascript loads modules as singletons when they are read, there for both A and B have the same instance of the `Thing` object.

Is this an example of the "service locator" pattern?

Comment: I'd call that useless `class` an antipattern.

Comment: Very classy response

Comment: Also please don't think in "patterns". Under certain circumstances, every pattern can be an antipattern. Use whatever makes sense to you, make your own judgement. I don't think that "service locator patterns" (just looked that up) are used in JS at all, and your modules aren't definetly doing something like that.

Comment: Of course, this is more just an academic question surrounding a system of managing dependencies prevalent in many languages.

Comment: Everything is just a term someone coined somewhere. Programming Patterns are certainly defined, just google for OOP Patterns. They help you solve common problems without you needing to reinvent the wheel.